# Nodejs - Express - Mysql: render view after post

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am using express to insert/list some records from a mysql db. Everything works fine (insert/select) but how do I render the list function after insert was completed? Do I have to re-invoke the select statement?

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

exports.create = function(req, res) {
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({user: 'root', password: 'password', database: 'test'});
  connection.query('INSERT INTO wall (message) VALUES ("' + req.body.message + '")', function(err, result) {
    if (err)
      throw err
    // is this correct? <===
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM wall', function(err, rows) {
      if (err)
        throw err
      if (rows)
        res.render('wall', {title: 'Wall', data: rows});
    });
    // end
    connection.end();
  });
};

exports.list = function(req, res) {
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({user: 'root', password: 'password',      database: 'test'});
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM wall', function(err, rows) {
    if (err)
      throw err
    if (rows)
      res.render('wall', {title: 'Wall', data: rows});
  });
  connection.end();
};
```

Comment: Are you accessing `exports.create` as an actual page or as a REST endpoint? or something else?

Comment: in app.js i have app.post('/wall', wall.create);
app.get('/wall', wall.list);

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do have to `SELECT` again, and your code is generally correct. I would refactor the common part between `list` and the part you're asking about, I would not list users and passwords in source files, and make other minor modifications, but generally it's correct.

Comment: ok, thanks for your reply Nitzan, i will investigate it a little more..:)

Answer (score 0):

I read the docs more carefully and i found

```
res.redirect();
```

so for my example, it works just fine to do

```
res.redirect('/wall');
```

to make a GET request to /wall route. The data will come as this route fetching the list of messages. Thats ok for me.